# How to pass non serializable objects to an intent service?

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, intentservice, serializable

I am using `AlarmManager` to schedule an `IntentService` to run some tasks periodically, but I will need to pass non-serializable instances to the service, which are required to run those tasks, since they are not serializable, I can't use `Intent` to pass them in. Also those instances can't be `static`, so what would be the best way to handle that?

Comment: What sort of objects are you talking about? Give an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `AlarmManager`, your process may not exist between events, and so those objects may not exist. Save the data to persistent storage (SQLite database, `SharedPreferences`, or other types of files) that the `IntentService` can read in. You could use a process-level cache to save on I/O time, in the chance that your process happens to remain around for consecutive events, but that is an optimization.